# How to create an ImmutableJS Record without default types?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

It appears that ImmutableJS Records need default values but I would prefer if they just threw runtime exceptions if fields are missing. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is no. From the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record):

> Values provided to the constructor not found in the Record type will be ignored.

Comment: This doesn't seem relevant to the question asked. The question asker is concerned with `Record`s' behaviour in the situation where a property *does* exist on the record type but is *not* included in the object passed to the record factory to construct such a record. (Specifically, he wants this to trigger an error.) Your quote, on the other hand, is about the situation where a property *does not* exist on the record type but *is* passed in the object passed to the record factory. That's the converse of what the question is about.